# Can we predict whether or not persons will favor legalization of marijuana based on sex and three categories of SES?

Tags: categorical-data

I am trying to figure out the relationship between a dichotomous independent variable sex, an ordinal three level SES independent variable predicting a dichotomous variable for legalization of pot or against. I am confused about what test to run.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you should be using logistic regression. Then you model

$log(\frac{\pi(x)}{1-\pi(x)}) = \beta_0 +\beta_1X_1 + \beta_2X_2$

where $\pi(x)$ is the probability of wanting to legalize pot, $X_1$ is sex (dummy coded, for instance) and $X_2$ is SES. The only problem is dealing with the ordinality of $X_2$; I do not know of ways to do that.

But regular logistic regression can be done in any statistics package.  Which one are you using?